# Post ArrayList of custom object in Jersey Client

Tags: jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I am trying to sent a custom arraylist of objects in Jersey, but no success at how this can be achieved.

My Clode,

```
 Response response = target.request().post( EntityList), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE));
```

How can this be achieved?

Regards,

Rohit

Answer (score 3):

The `post` method comes in three flavors

- [`Response post(Entity<?> entity)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/SyncInvoker.html#post%28javax.ws.rs.client.Entity%29)
- [`<T> T post(Entity<?> entity, Class<T> responseType)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/SyncInvoker.html#post%28javax.ws.rs.client.Entity,%20java.lang.Class%29)
- [`<T> T post(Entity<?> entity, GenericType<T> responseType)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/SyncInvoker.html#post%28javax.ws.rs.client.Entity,%20javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType%29)

Since you want to just get an `Response` back, you will use the first one. As you can see it accepts an [`Entity`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Entity.html). This class has a static [`json`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Entity.html#json%28T%29) method, that you can pass an arbitrary object to. As long as you have a serializer (provider like Jackson) to handle this marshalling (and have configured it, if necessary), then something something like below should work fine

```
Response response = target.request().post(Entity.json(entityList));
```

If you get an exception about no MessageBodyWriter is found, then try to add this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

This should automatically register with your `Client` (version 2.9 and up).